# No soft keyboard for the EditText inside the Dialog Box

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, dialog

I'd like to create a Dialog Box where the user can insert a number; so I overrided the onCreateDialog method this way:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            EditText editNum=new EditText(this);
            editNum.setMaxLines(1);
            editNum.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            String strVal=listViewNum.getItemAtPosition(selectedItem).toString();
            strVal=strVal.substring(strVal.indexOf("=")+1,strVal.length()-1);
            editNum.setText(Util.formatNumber(Double.parseDouble(strVal)));
            editNum.selectAll();
            editNum.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.RIGHT);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.DialogEditNumberTitle))
            .setView(editNum)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Annulla", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
            })
            .create();
    }
```

But despite this I'm still allowed to insert non-numeric characters and there is no sign of the soft keyboard...what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you could do programmatically, BUT you could create your own custom layout which will contain an edittext as follows:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/myEditText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:inputType="numbers"
android:digits="0123456789"/>
```

and then in the code for the onCreateDialog:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, null); //I showed this as a linear layout before, but it must be a view to inflate it
        EditText myEditText = (EditText)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        //create myEditText listener here, if needed




dialog.setView(myLayout);
```

Comment: What exceptions specifically and what lines do they happen at?