# Android: Show Soft Keyboard in Custom AlertDialog on EditText Focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, show, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom AlertDialog come up, but when you tap on the EditText fields in the layout, the soft keyboard doesn't automatically come up.  I tried this solution [Android: EditText in Dialog doesn't pull up soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102074/android-edittext-in-dialog-doesnt-pull-up-soft-keyboard) using:

`dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);`

It might be as simple as I am not putting the code in the correct location.  I tried it in the onCreateDialog and onPrepareDialog of the Activity as well as the constructor and onCreate of the custom AlertDialog.  That did not work.

I'd prefer this solution as this would seem best practices over trying to have a onFocus listener for the EditText fields.

How I've tried it in the Activity

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (id) {
    case LOCATION_DETAILS_DIALOG:
        dialog = new LocationDetails(this, detailsSetListener);
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
        return dialog;

    default:
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onPrepareDialog(final int id,final Dialog dialog){
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
    case LOCATION_DETAILS_DIALOG:
       dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    }
}
```

How I've tried it in the AlertDialog class

```
public LocationDetails(Context context, DetailsSetEventListener detailsSetEventListener) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.detailsSetEventListener = detailsSetEventListener;
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

Any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: So I assume that the AlertDialog suppresses the keyboard since it is just to provide a message and OK/Cancel buttons.  It should just be used as a prompt.

So I just changed the base class of my custom Dialog to Dialog.  By just changing the base class my custom Dialog inherits from, the EditText fields will pull up the soft / virtual keyboard when they receive focus, just like you would expect.

Answer (score 10):

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

works fine for me, I put it in the constructor, such as

```
public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        show();
        setContentView(R.layout.widget_custom_dialog);

        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    }
```

Change AlertDialog to Dialog will cause the wrong dialog position for me, so I use this method.

Comment: Noting that clearFlags will only work if you call it after show.

Comment: Worked well for me when I used it in `onStart` (using it before `show` would crash it with a NullPointerException)